# Auto-generate DataTable from DB2 schema

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, datatable, db2

I'm working on a project where we have a pre-existing `DataSet`. We don't do any persistence type stuff. It just acts as a holder for data we read in from DB2.

I need to add a new column to one of the tables. I can open the designer and see the `DataTable`... I could manually add the column of course, but I was wondering if there's a way to tell Visual Studio to go get the table schema from DB2 and build the `DataTable` for me? It'd be pretty cool if that would also handle easily updating it with schema changes in the future. I'd want my `DataTable`/`DataSet` to be strongly-typed, which is something have right now with manually adding columns in the designer.

I haven't had much luck finding any tutorials. An [intermediate solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317940) might be to generate `XSD` from the DB2 schema and import that, but considering my lack of knowledge in this area, I thought it'd be good to get some input from others.

Comment: You might want to look at Entity Framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.. a search on POCO (Plain Old CLR Object) should return you many happy results.  (NB, this is a "joke" on the term POJO).

Of course this is stackoverflow.com so you *could* use the one they wrote... it is at:

http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

I don't recommend EF, it is a little heavy for a quick-n-easy solution.

Good luck.

Comment: That's a neat project. Agreed on the overkill of EF part... since I can't really modify the project I'm working on to that great of a degree, I'm still looking for a solution involving automagically updating (or producing) a DataTable. Thanks for your answer! I'll probably give a try on my next project.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question -- if you just want a DataTable and not the data why not use the .NET driver and select as normal?

Comment: Yea, I might be missing something really obvious here. But to clarify, I'm not worried about filling the `DataTable`, I'm trying to find a better way to update our `DataTable` with schema changes than manually editing it in the designer... and hoping that the same method could be used to create it in the first place.

Comment: This is what I don't understand.  DataTable's are run-time objects... what exactly is getting updated?  There is no database there is no source code.  I'm mystified what you mean.  Maybe if you posted some code with the problem area I could help.  (To be clear, I've had a couple of projects where a given DataTable would change schema with different users or at different times... so I understand why you want changes, just not why it is a problem.  Maybe it is just the way you are using the DataTable?)

Comment: I think you're talking about creating a `DataTable` in code at run-time yes? I'm talking about the designer view seen in this screenshot: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0146e3/crystal-report-in-visual-studio-2010/Images/t11.gif

Comment: Sure.  But there is a design conflict here.  Why would you need to do this (which is the same as defining your DB structure in compiled code) if you expect that structure to change.  This is the disconnect I don't understand.  It seems (from here) like a fundamental bad design smell.  For example, what in your system relies on an XSD -- this part is probably badly designed.

Comment: Agreed. Fortunately I didn't write it ;) I'll just have to make sure not to emulate it. Really all we do it load up the table and then pull stuff from the columns strongly-typed: dapper-dot-net would probably be a better solution :)